# What does the 'single' mean here?

Tags: python

Here is the instruction:
a string "fig_type", which is one of the two values: "single" or "subplots".
The input argument "fig_type" determines how to draw the plots:

if "fig_type" is "single", you should produce one set of axes, draw all the plots together in the same axes, and differentiate them e.g. by line or marker colour or style.
if "fig_type" is "subplots", you should produce 
r
different sets of axes (in the same figure), so that each plot is drawn in a different subplot. Choose how to set up your subplots so that all plots are sufficiently large and readable.

Then I write a code like that, I'm not quite sure if that's how it should be written, and I'm not sure what single means in this context.

```
if fig_type =='single':
    fig, ax = plt.plot()
else:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Comment: By your description: single = if "fig_type" is "single", you should produce one set of axes, draw all the plots together in the same axes, and differentiate them e.g. by line or marker colour or style.

Comment: Yeah, I get that! And I am wondering in which conditions I need to have only one graph with numerous lines.

Comment: So I shouldn’t use ‘single’ as the command right?

Comment: The plt.subplots will be able to visualize multiple graphs where you can seperate lines or graphs. While if you have the condition "single" I understand it as you must do all the lines in one graph, and that is what you will do in the "single" condition that you have written. It will create 1 graph where you can plot multiple lines. IMO it's correct as presented.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining those to me!! I think I get it now!